# How to add a custom icon to Setup Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, icons

I am trying to add a custom icon to setup project. So instead of standard installer logo I have my custom logo.

To make it clear, here is the icon, which I want to change:

[image: installer icon]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right-click the Setup Project in Solution Explorer and select *View > User Interface*.

This will display all the screens of the installer.

The picture that you want to change is the property **BannerBitmap**.

You can customize this for any screen of the installer.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to **dhirschl**'s answer ... you also have the option to change the default BannerBitmap so that all your setups have your own logo automatically and you don't have to worry about fixing it every time you create a new setup.

Clear instructions on how to do this are provided by **René van Bemmelen** and can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/cbd15180-c890-4c67-a7ff-0804b524da6d) on the Microsoft forums.